# How to install python36 and python36-dev in docker: oraclelinux:7-slim

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, oraclelinux

Below is Dockerfile. I tired with many combination. Its not working. I need to user Oraclelinux. I am planning to use docker for local development and testing purpose. Could you please help me on this.

> ```
>   FROM oraclelinux:7-slim
>
> # Installing Oracle Instant client
> RUN yum -y install oracle-release-el7 && \
>     yum-config-manager --enable ol7_oracle_instantclient && \
>     yum -y install oracle-instantclient19.3-basiclite && \
>     rm -rf /var/cache/yum
>
> # Installing Python and cs_oracle package
> RUN yum install -y oracle-epel-release-el7 && \
>     yum install -y python36 && \
>     yum install -y python36-dev
> ```

Error:

```
Package python36-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by python3-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Processing Dependency: python36-libs(x86-64) = 3.6.8-1.el7 for package: python36-devel-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64
Package python36-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by python3-libs-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python36-devel-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_developer_EPEL)
           Requires: python36 = 3.6.8-1.el7
           Installed: python3-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64 (@ol7_latest)
               python36 = 3.6.8-13.0.1.el7
           Available: python3-3.6.8-10.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               python36 = 3.6.8-10.0.1.el7
           Available: python36-3.6.3-7.el7.x86_64 (ol7_developer_EPEL)
               python36 = 3.6.3-7.el7
           Available: python36-3.6.6-1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_developer_EPEL)
               python36 = 3.6.6-1.el7
           Available: python36-3.6.6-2.el7.x86_64 (ol7_developer_EPEL)
               python36 = 3.6.6-2.el7
           Available: python36-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_developer_EPEL)
               python36 = 3.6.8-1.el7
Error: Package: python36-devel-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_developer_EPEL)
           Requires: python36-libs(x86-64) = 3.6.8-1.el7
           Installed: python3-libs-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64 (@ol7_latest)
               python36-libs(x86-64) = 3.6.8-13.0.1.el7
           Available: python3-libs-3.6.8-10.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               python36-libs(x86-64) = 3.6.8-10.0.1.el7
           Available: python36-libs-3.6.3-7.el7.x86_64 (ol7_developer_EPEL)
               python36-libs(x86-64) = 3.6.3-7.el7
           Available: python36-libs-3.6.6-1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_developer_EPEL)
               python36-libs(x86-64) = 3.6.6-1.el7
           Available: python36-libs-3.6.6-2.el7.x86_64 (ol7_developer_EPEL)
               python36-libs(x86-64) = 3.6.6-2.el7
           Available: python36-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_developer_EPEL)
               python36-libs(x86-64) = 3.6.8-1.el7
```

Comment: There is already a  python36 image, is there any particular reason to use oracle7-slim? You can have multi-stage builds with different base images

Comment: I am trying to replicate existing dev server setup in docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Dockerfiles in the [oracle/docker-images/OracleLinuxDevelopers](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleLinuxDevelopers) repository.

There are 2 examples:

- `oraclelinux7-python:3.6` is Python 3.6 on top of oraclelinux:7-slim
- `oraclelinux7-python:3.6-oracledb` has the same python version, but also includes the Oracle Instant Client package

Comment: Both the images are not included python.h files.

Comment: @HardikPatira -- 

If you need the header files, you need to install the `python3-devel` package as well:

`yum install -y --enablerepo ol7_optional_latest python3-devel`

Comment: yum install -y --enablerepo ol7_optional_latest python3-devel this worked. Thanks..!! :)

How did you find out? what is approach i need to follow if get any issue with the package version?

Comment: The Python3 environment on Oracle Linux 7 can be a bit intricate as OL7 has been released quite some time ago and different Python 3 versions were made available through different channels over time. Oracle Linux 7.7 and newer include Python 3 in the base distribution (ol7_latest /  ol7_optional_latest repos) and is the recommended version to use. There is list of all available versions at http://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-python.html (I'll see if we can make a reference to ol7_optional_latest on that page)

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to install a version of python which is obseleted by another version of python. In this case, you can try uninstalling the current version of python and install the specific version you are trying to install.

Hope it works!  :)